# Cron job not working? Setting wordpress cron through SSH Crontab

Tags: wordpress, cron

I am trying to set, using Putty SSH access, the external cron of a wordpress website to run every hour

So I access my server SSH, run crontab -e

add the command:

0 * * * * https://mywebsite.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1

press ESC + :wp to save
as you can confirm here the crontab -l
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0sac.jpg

However I am checking Cron logs and it doesn't run at all

Any idea what is going on / what am I missing?

Comment: you forgot to add command which fetches the file, i.e. curl or wget. do not forget to specify full path to binary (i.e. ```0 * * * * /usr/bin/curl https://mywebsite.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1```)

Comment: Thank you! indeed what worked was adding wget -q -O to it :)
`0 * * * * wget -q -O - https:// mywebsite.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1`

and it worked perfectly :)